# HTML5 Picture element does not seem to be supported by Chrome 52? Srcset not working

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, picturefill

I just started a new webpage so there's not much markup to go over.

I set this down:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1000px)"
            srcset="images/largeme.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)"
            srcset="images/medme.jpg">
    <img src="images/smallme.jpg"alt="hero profile">
</picture>
```

and it defaults to the medme.jpg picture no matter the width of the window. I set down this:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1000px)"
            srcset="images/largeme.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)"
            srcset="images/medme.jpg">
   <!-- <img src="images/smallme.jpg"alt="hero profile">-->
</picture>
```

commenting out the img fallback tag and it doesn't show anything.

I'm running Chrome 52 which should support picture element. But it seems to be acting as if it doesn't support it or something. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the images are being served? Check the network requests in the Network tab of dev tools

Answer (score 31):

The `img` element inside the `picture` element isn't optional. The `picture` wrapper and its `source` elements are there to *change* the `img`, not replace it.

Comment: EXACTLY what i needed. That totally got me. I thought the `img` tag was for compatibility fallback, but it's actually used for the render.

Comment: omg I've just wasted so much time, just because  everywhere in the internet it is written (and stressed out) that <img> is for fallback. While actually it is the one obligatory element inside <picture>.... Thanks @rspeed

Comment: But it does not work. It always renders the image in the img src, ignoring the others.

Comment: @ChinmayGhule Make sure the `img` is the *last* child of the `picture` element.

Comment: @rspeed I did do that but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

It should work in chrome, maybe you need the viewport meta-tag to trigger the different sources? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` [Here is a simple picture-tag example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-element/) which works in chrome. Compare it with your site to find out what is different.

Comment: I'm actually copy pasting from that example website :/ idk what's up with it. I eventually got it to work, but it still is acting in an unexpected way. I don't know why

Answer (score 5):

It sounds silly, but have you tried reverting the order? For some reason doing this made it work for me.

So, instead of:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1000px)"
            srcset="images/largeme.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)"
            srcset="images/medme.jpg">
    <img src="images/smallme.jpg"alt="hero profile">
</picture>
```

try this:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)"
            srcset="images/medme.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 1000px)"
            srcset="images/largeme.jpg">
    <img src="images/smallme.jpg"alt="hero profile">
</picture>
```

Comment: Great idea, this got me because it WAS changing the image as expected but does NOT change the image's path in the `<img>` tag. Don't get tricked!

Answer (score 1):

You must set a max-width for the lower width image, otherwise it is the only one always served (you can see it in devtools network tab if you try).

Like this

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1000px)"
            srcset="images/largeme.jpg">
    <source media="(max-width: 999px)"
            srcset="images/medme.jpg">
    <img src="images/smallme.jpg"alt="hero profile">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_media.asp) the `<source>` media attribute is not being supported at all...

Comment: w3schools has been falling behind on current spec lately.

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/),  support is conditional on enabling experimental Web Platform features in chrome://flags