# <source> Tag Isn't Displaying, Even Though Image is Fine?

Tags: html

I have an example with code directly copied from the MDN, except with my own image URLs instead:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="/images/site/logo.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="/images/site/logo.png" alt="logo" />
</picture>
```

Both images ("logo.webp" and "logo.png") work when I browse directly to them.  However, when I inspect the above code in my browser, the inspector focuses on the `<img>` tag, *not* the `<source>`.  If I then delete the `<img>`, the image itself disappears from the page ... even though you'd expect it to fall back to the `<source>`.

It really seems like my `<source>` isn't even being used, but I don't understand why.  Its corresponding image does work (I can even put the `.webp` path into the `<img>` tag, and it displays just fine).

What am I not understanding here about `<picture>` and `<source>`?

**EDIT:** Even if I change the HTML itself to the full URL of the *PNG* file (not even the WebP one), it still doesn't display anything:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="http://localhost:3000/images/site/logo.png"> 
</picture>
```

Shouldn't a single `picture`/`source` tag be enough to display an image (again, with a path that works perfectly fine in an `<img>` tag)?  Or am I misunderstanding `<picture>` somehow?

Comment: I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236087/html5-picture-element-does-not-seem-to-be-supported-by-chrome-52-srcset-not-wor which answered my question: the `<img>` is *not* optional! It actually *is* what the browser displays; the picture/source tags simply *set the src of the* `<img>`.  Thus, the browser was correctly showing me that I was using the `<img>` ... I just didn't understand the `<source>` was overriding the `<img>` `src` attribute.

Comment: P.S. In the Chrome Dev Tools, if you inspect the `<img>` and hover over the `src` value, Chrome will actually display a box above it that includes "Current source".  This will show the *actual* source of the `<img>` (eg. the `.webp` version instead of the `.png` one in my example).